# Передать в переменную фото полученное в aiogram (python)

Tags: python, download, aiogram

пытаюсь при помощи бота aiogram получить фото от пользователя, и передать для обработки дальше в PIL (не сохраняя на диск). Получил что то подобное:

```
image = BytesIO()

@dp.message_handler(content_types='photo')
async def photo_handler(message: types.Message):
    message.photo[-1].download(image)
    #тут вроде как надо перейти в начала буфера
    image.seek(0)

    #дальше пока просто смотрю тип данных в переменной.
    await message.answer(type(image))
```

Но не знаю что делать дальше... Пока не уверен что вообще двигаюсь в правильном направлении.
По идее надо принять BytesIO и сохранить в памяти в формате JPG, но как не пытался у меня это не получилось...
(учусь только, знаний маловато).

Comment: Вы можете записать байт-код фотографии в переменную

Comment: Да, но как этот байт код потом открыть в Pillow...

Comment: Можно записать в файл

Comment: with open('file.png', 'wb') as file: file.write(bytecode)

Comment: И потом также открыть как rb, если нужна работа с файлом. Тут много вариантов. Можно использовать модуль PIL

Answer (score 0):

```
image = BytesIO()

#Фото надо отправить в виде файла
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
async def photo_handler(message: types.Message):
    bytes = message.document.thumb.download(destination=image)
    
    #Вывод байт-обьекта
    print(bytes.read())

    #тип данных в переменной - io.BytesIO
    await message.answer(type(image))
```

Используете присвоения параметру destination значения екземпляра класа BytesIO.